# My Method doesn't load when i called it to another Method - PHP

Tags: php, slim

i don't know why my method is not working when it is being loaded to other method .. it doesn't give any PHP ERROR, so i don't know where & how to debug it ..
have you experience this??

here's my code ..

this is the method where i want my other method being loaded

```
    public function show($request, $response){

    $status = $request->getParam('status');
    $refno = $request->getParam('refno');
    $msg = urldecode($request->getParam('message'));
    $refx = explode(' ', $msg);

    do {
        // $reference_number = $this->randomlib->generateString(20, '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ');
        $reference_number = $this->randomlib->generateString(5, '0123456789'); //transaction id for dragonpay
        $reference_number_exist = $this->db->table('order_payment')->where('reference_number', $reference_number)->exists();
    } while ($reference_number_exist === true);     

    switch ($request->getParam('status')) {
        case 'S':
            return $this->view->render($response, 'portal/dragonpay-success/view.twig',[
                'refno' => $refno,
                'status' => $status,
                'message' => $refx[4]
            ]);
            $this->DragonpayPayment($request, $response, $reference_number);
            break;
        case 'P':
            return $this->view->render($response, 'portal/dragonpay-pending/view.twig',[
                'status' => $status,
                'refno' => $refno
            ]);
            break;
        case 'F':
            return $this->view->render($response, 'portal/dragonpay-failed/view.twig',[
                'refno' => $refno,
                'status' => $status,
                'message' => $msg
            ]);
            break;                              
    }

}
```

and here's the method that i want to be loaded

```
    public function DragonpayPayment($request, $response, $reference_number){

    $amount = '';

    //insert transaction in db
    $transaction = $this->auth->user()->order()->create([
        'order_type_id' => $this->db->table('sys_mf_order_type')->where('order_type_name', 'add-balance')->first()->order_type_id,
        'store_id'      => $this->schoolAdmin->getStoreAdministratorDetail('store_id'),
        'status'        => 'completed',
        'order_for_id'  => 0,
        'remarks'       => 'Load-up DragonPay',
        'school_id'     => $this->schoolAdmin->school_id
    ]);

    $transaction->orderPayment()->create([
        'payment_type'     => 'DragonPay',
        'amount'           => $amount,
        'reference_number' => sha1($reference_number),
        'school_id'        => $this->school->school_id
    ]);

}
```

it doesn't give any error so i dont know how to debug it, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> For Error debug in PHP use this code in method

```
var_dump('variable data');die();
```

> OR

```
print_r('varible data');die();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have at least one problem: your call to `DragonpayPayment()` in the `case 'S'` part is an `unreachable statement`, because it finds itself AFTER the `return` statement.

```
return $this->view->render(/*...*/);
$this->DragonpayPayment($request, $response, $reference_number);
```

Write:

```
$this->DragonpayPayment($request, $response, $reference_number);
return $this->view->render(/*...*/);
```

Also: use only a `while` statement, not a `do-while`. Also... your `do-while` makes no sense in your form.
Delete it and just write the vars instead:

```
// $reference_number = $this->randomlib->generateString(20, '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ');
$reference_number = $this->randomlib->generateString(5, '0123456789'); //transaction id for dragonpay
$reference_number_exist = $this->db->table('order_payment')->where('reference_number', $reference_number)->exists();
```

And use

```
switch ($status) {...}
```

instead of

```
switch ($request->getParam('status')) {...}
```

### EDIT 1:

Try to use a basic exception handling. So, into `DragonpayPayment()` encapsulate your code inside a `try-catch` block:

```
public function DragonpayPayment($request, $response, $reference_number) {
    try {
        $amount = '';

        //insert transaction in db
        $transaction = $this->auth->user()->order()->create([
            'order_type_id' => $this->db->table('sys_mf_order_type')->where('order_type_name', 'add-balance')->first()->order_type_id,
            'store_id' => $this->schoolAdmin->getStoreAdministratorDetail('store_id'),
            'status' => 'completed',
            'order_for_id' => 0,
            'remarks' => 'Load-up DragonPay',
            'school_id' => $this->schoolAdmin->school_id
        ]);

        $transaction->orderPayment()->create([
            'payment_type' => 'DragonPay',
            'amount' => $amount,
            'reference_number' => sha1($reference_number),
            'school_id' => $this->school->school_id
        ]);
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($exception, true) . '</pre>';
        exit();
    }
}
```

And run all again.

Comment: @DistortedMankind You're welcome. About what I said regarding the `while` statement (to be deleted), I'm not so sure. You know better, what it should do. Anyway, I also recommend you to never use `while` statements. They are very risky, e.g. can be the source of very bad infinite loops. Use `for` instead.

Comment: @DistortedMankind Oh, and if your call to `DragonpayPayment()` still don't work, then your `$status` variable is not gaining the value `'S'` at all.

Comment: it is not inserting into the database, its still not working @aendeerei ..

Comment: @DistortedMankind Is your `DragonpayPayment()` called from inside the switch case `'S'` now?

Comment: no, its a different method .. but i want to call `DragonpayPayment()` inside `show()`

Comment: @DistortedMankind Sorry, don't want to be unpolite. But I only have just 10 minutes more. I stay here for this time if you need my help.

Comment: @DistortedMankind You're welcome. So, tell me, have you tested again?